# How do I make the score increase when all cactuses goes off the screen in Python pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I want to make the score increase when all types of cactuses go off the screen.

Right now, how it works is by having a function `random_cactus()` that generates 2 different types of cactuses, big and normal. However it only works when the normal cactus goes off the screen, instead of both big and normal, please fix this.

```
import pygame
import sys
import time
import random

# Initialize pygame
pygame.init()

# Screen dimensions and setup
screen_width, screen_height = 1000, 500
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Desert Run")

class Button:
    def __init__(self, text, x_pos, y_pos, enabled, color):
        self.text = text
        self.x_pos = x_pos
        self.y_pos = y_pos
        self.enabled = enabled
        self.color = color
        self.draw( )
    
    def draw(self):
        button_text = font.render(self.text, True, self.color)
        button_rect = pygame.Rect((self.x_pos, self.y_pos),(150, 55))
        if self.enabled:
            if self.check_click():
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, 'dark gray', button_rect, 0, 5)
            else:
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, 'gray', button_rect, 0, 5)
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, 'black', button_rect, 0, 5)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, 'black',button_rect, 2, 5)
        screen.blit(button_text, (self.x_pos + 13, self.y_pos + 10))
    
    def check_click(self):
        mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        left_click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]
        button_rect = pygame.Rect((self.x_pos, self.y_pos),(150, 55))
        if left_click and button_rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos) and self.enabled:
            return True
        else:
            return False

# Clock for controlling the frame rate
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Colors
sky_blue = (135, 206, 235)
sand_color = (252, 221, 96)
black = (0, 0, 0)

# Player properties
player_x, player_y = 50, 270
player_gravity = 1
jump_height = 20
y_velocity = jump_height
is_jumping = False
lost = False
new_press = True
main_menu = True

# Load images
player_image = pygame.image.load('Desert Run/player.png').convert()
# Load cactus images
cactus_image = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('Desert Run/Cactus.png'), (60, 100)).convert_alpha()
big_cactus_image = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('Desert Run/bigcactus.png'), (120, 100)).convert_alpha()
main_menu_image = pygame.image.load('Desert Run/Main Menu.png').convert_alpha()
cacti = []

# Font setup
font = pygame.font.Font(None, 50)

# Function to create a random cactus
def create_random_cactus():
    random_cactus = random.choice([cactus_image, big_cactus_image])
    cactus_x = 1000
    cactus_height = random_cactus.get_height()
    cactus_y = 220 + (100 - cactus_height)  # Adjust this value as needed for positioning
    if random_cactus == big_cactus_image:
        return big_cactus_image, cactus_x ,cactus_y
    else:
        return cactus_image, cactus_x, cactus_y

# Game loop
score = 0
cactus_spawn_timer = 0
cactus_spawn_interval = 150

while True:
    while main_menu:
        # Main menu
        screen.fill(sky_blue)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, sand_color, [0, 320, screen_width, 200])
        screen.blit(main_menu_image, (355, 100))
        start_button = Button("Start", 420, 250, True, (0, 0, 0))
        if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] and new_press:
            new_press = False
            if start_button.check_click():
                main_menu = False
                score = 0
                cactus_x = 900
        if not pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] and not new_press:
            new_press = True
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
        pygame.display.update()
    else:
        while not lost:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()

            keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

            if (keys[pygame.K_SPACE] or keys[pygame.K_w]) and not is_jumping:
                is_jumping = True
                y_velocity = -jump_height

            # Apply gravity
            y_velocity += player_gravity
            player_y += y_velocity

            if player_y > 270:
                player_y = 270
                is_jumping = False

            # Move and create cacti
            cactus_x -= 8
            if len(cacti) == 0 or cacti[-1][1] < screen_width - 400:
                random_cactus, cactus_x, cactus_y = create_random_cactus()
                cacti.append([random_cactus, cactus_x, cactus_y])

            # Initialize a variable to keep track of cacti that have been scored
            scored_cacti = []

            # Draw everything
            screen.fill(sky_blue)
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, sand_color, [0, 320, screen_width, 200])

            # Display the score
            text_surface = font.render(f"Score: {score}", True, black)
            screen.blit(text_surface, (10, 10))
            for cactus in cacti:
                cactus[1] -= 8  # Move cacti to the left
    
                #cactus[1] = x_pos of the cactus
                #cactus[2] = y_pos of the cactus
                screen.blit(cactus[0], (cactus[1], cactus[2]))
                print(cactus[0])

                if cactus[1] < -cactus[0].get_width():
                    scored_cacti.append(cactus)
                    print(scored_cacti)
                    score += 1

            cacti = [cactus for cactus in cacti if cactus[1] > -cactus[0].get_width()]
            player_hitbox = pygame.draw.rect(screen, black, (player_x, player_y, 50, 50))
            screen.blit(player_image, (player_x, player_y))

            if player_hitbox.collidelist([pygame.Rect(cactus[1], cactus[2], cactus[0].get_width(), cactus[0].get_height()) for cactus in cacti]) != -1:
                lost = True

            pygame.display.update()
            clock.tick(60)
        else:
            # Losing screen
            losing_text = font.render("You've Lost", True, 'red')
            screen.blit(losing_text, (410, 100))
            restart_button = Button('Restart?', 425, 200, True, (255, 0, 0))
            score_text = font.render(f"Your score is {score}", True, "black")
            screen.blit(score_text, (410, 150))
            if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] and new_press:
                new_press = False
                if restart_button.check_click():
                    lost = False
                    score = 0
                    cacti = []
            if not pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] and not new_press:
                new_press = True
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
            pygame.display.update()
```

I expected the score to increase when both types of cactuses go off the screen.

Answer (score 1):

In your particular case, since cacti are moving to the left only

```py
            for cactus in cacti:
                cactus[1] -= 8  # Move cacti to the left
    
                #cactus[1] = x_pos of the cactus
                #cactus[2] = y_pos of the cactus
                screen.blit(cactus[0], (cactus[1], cactus[2]))
                print(cactus[0])

                if cactus[1] < -cactus[0].get_width():
                    scored_cacti.append(cactus)
                    print(scored_cacti)
                    score += 1
```

you want to check if the value `cactus[1]` is negative, since the screen starts at x = 0 that should mean the cacti is outside the screen.

Probably the correct way would be to check if the value is negative whatever the width of the image is.

So if `cactus[1]` is 0 then it just reached the border, if it's negative is halfway out and if it's negative the width of the image it just disappeared from the screen.

If the cacti could moved everywhere you would have to check all boundaries.